# Get currently selected option onBlur in html select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a Select element in my react Component:

```html
<select
    id={id}
    value={value || ''}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
>

<option value="">Please select a value</option>
{items.map(item => (
    <option value={item.key} key={item.key}>
        {item.value}
    </option>
))}
```

On the onBlur function I want to get the value prop of the currently selected option element in the select list.

```js
    onBlur = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        // want to get the currently selected options value here
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `state` for  storing the value of selected data.Then get the data from state when  `onBlur` is called

```
<select
    id={id}
    value={this.state.selectedValue}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
>

<option value="">Please select a value</option>
{items.map(item => (
    <option value={item.key} key={item.key}>
        {item.value}
    </option>
))}
onChange(event) {
this.setState({'selectedValue':event.target.value})
}
onBlur() {
console.log(this.state.selectedValue)
}
```